# how to open an url in a browser automatically through javascript or jquery just after installing a provisioning profile on ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, provisioning-profile

actually i have placed profvisioning profile in root directory in a folder '**CerProv**' as `'CerProv/deviceprofile.mobileprovision'`.
now i am trying to install it by executing it through javascript like this:

```
window.open("CerProv/deviceprofile.mobileprovision");
```

whenever the above line of code is executed the browser window disappears and provision profile installing window is opened. then i clicked on 'intall' button and profile started installing. upto here its working perfectly. but now what i want that after finshing installation of profile the browser window should appear back automatically....

here is the example: 
open this url on an ios device 
http://m.freemyapps.com/ios_enrollment/new

i want the same functionality as that of above url.

is there any solution for that...
any kind of help will really be appreciated. i am badly needing this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the 'pageshow' event.
Here is the full HAML solution

```
.modal.fade
  .modal-header
    %h1 Sync XXX to your iPhone
  .modal-body
    %p Some explanation
  .modal-footer
    = link_to "OK", apple_sync_profile_user_url, class: 'btn btn-primary add-profile'

- content_for :bottom do
  :javascript
    var clicked = false;

    $('.add-profile').click(function() {
      clicked = true;
    });

    var redirect = function () {
      if(clicked)
        window.location = 'CerProv/deviceprofile.mobileprovision';
    };

    window.addEventListener('pageshow', redirect, false);
    $('.modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: true})
```

**Edit**

An adaptation to Dimpal's code:

```
//on the click of a button
$('#popup .enroll').click(function(){
$('#popup').hide('100');
$('#wrapper1').css('opacity','1');
$('#wrapper1 a').attr('onclick','return true');
// after hitting the following url the browser window disappears and profile installation window of ios device will open....
window.open("CerProv/taxiopen-1.mobileprovision");
//now whenever the profile installation on ios device will be completed i want the current browser window to be opened automatically and start execution from the just next line automatically i.e. it should redirect on this url
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function() {window.open("getstarted.html");});

});
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but i am not able to implement it in my code..
so can u please help me to integrate your code in my code.

here is my code in the following the above answer:-